# Automating removal of credits (citations) assigned to layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, layers, feature-class

I have been given a map document with ~130 feature classes which have been symbolized, etc.  In the layer properties, on the General Tab, credits have been written in.  When published to ArcGIS Online as a hosted feature service, these credits stream into the display area of the map.

Is there a way to automate the removal of the credits via python?

I thought perhaps arcpy.Describe but there doesn't seem to be a method or property for credits.

[image: layer property credits]

Answer (score 4):

The `layer` object in `arcpy.mapping` has a `credits` property that

> Provides the ability to either get or set the layer's credits or copyright information.

Since the credits were set in the project, not the data, you will have to remove them in the project, then re-publish the project to ArcGIS Online.